# How to make this site work in non-firefox browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This page displays beautifully in firefox but i get all kinds of problems when testing the site in opera or internet explorer, mostly with the menu. I would like to know what techniques have caused this and how to avoid them.

http://www.jkhbdesign.se/

Edit 2: Here are some screenshots of some specific problems

The dropdown as it should look:

[alt text http://nibbo.se/slask/correct.png](http://nibbo.se/slask/correct.png)

The way it looks in IE 7:

[alt text http://nibbo.se/slask/dropdownie.png](http://nibbo.se/slask/dropdownie.png)

The way it looks in Opera:

[alt text http://nibbo.se/slask/dropdownopera.png](http://nibbo.se/slask/dropdownopera.png)

Comment: More info would be useful... Perhaps a link, or a description of the code involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least you are going to have to deal with the fact that the CSS :hover is not supported in IE for any tag except the anchor tag.  You'll need to use onmouseover, onmouseout in IE to accomplish the same thing.  Or change the li:hover to an a:hover but that would be a bigger overhaul of your design I think.

Specifically, CSS like this:

```
ul.menu li:hover ul.submenu {
background:white none repeat scroll 0 0;
border:1px solid #A6A6A6;
display:block;
margin-left:-25px;
margin-top:23px;
padding:2px 0;
position:absolute;
}
```

Is not going to work properly in Internet Explorer.  I don't know about Opera.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with a [site I created](http://www.stannscatholicschool.com).  The problem ended up being that I shouldn't have ended the `<li>` tag before the next `<ul>` tag started in the menu.

For example:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul><a href="/index.html">Home</a>

    <li><a href="/aboutus/index.html">About Us</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/aboutus/history.html">History</a>
```

Note no closing `</li>` tag.

I ran into a lot of problems with IE and CSS Menus. I recommend the following resources, they may save you a lot of time:

- http://www.seoconsultants.com/css/menus/horizontal/
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns

Let me know how that goes.

For what it's worth, the first resource includes a csshover.htc file and its usage -- which the site I created uses to fix the issues caused with Internet Explorer. If you view the source for the site, you'll also see conditional comments that pertain to Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the CSS for your site, I suspect that you are using css:hover with Lists to create the menu. IE doesn't support this, so you have to supply a behaviour file to allow IE to have the functionality,
[Link with a file here](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with javascript, you might want to look into the JQuery Superfish plugin. (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Superfish).  Most of the hard work and weird browser issues are already taken care of for you.